# Simple way to undo a lot of table-specific grants in MySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I have set up some table specific grants in MySQL, but when I log on as that MySQL-user it still has full access to all tables. I'd like to wipe all the GRANTs and start them over.

I'm running a Debian Linux server, using command line commands like:

```
GRANT INSERT on database.someTable TO 'everyone'@'localhost';
```

(multiplied times 30 or so.)

Trying to revoke the grants using the single command below just yields some error saying that there wasn't a grant of that type to remove:

```
REVOKE all on database.* FROM 'everyone'@'localhost';
```

Do I have to try to reverse engineer the grants and REVOKE them each individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';` will show you all of the grant commands applied for a given user, you can then change them to revokes to reverse them.

Generally a good idea to run a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` before testing, as well.

Comment: That combined with a delete of the user via mysqladmin allowed me to get it into a better state.